# Changing order of db results when encoding to JSON

Tags: database, mysql, json

There is probably a very simple solution to this but I just can't work it out.

I am getting some info from the wp database, bypassing WP's built in classes, then echoing the results as encoded JSON data like this :

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'dbusername', 'dbpassword');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = 'SELECT user_login AS name, display_name AS tag, user_status AS status
FROM wp_users';

$query = $db->query($sql);
$i = 1;
$data = array();
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$row['id'] = $i;
$i++;
$data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

This outputs the following :

```
[ 
    {
        "name": "johndoe",
        "tag": "John Doe",
        "status": "0",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "janedoe",
        "tag": "Jane Doe",
        "status": "0",
        "id": 2
    }
]
```

But I need to change the order of the listings for a jquery plug-in that I'm using. I need the "id" tag to render first like this :

```
[ 
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "johndoe",
        "tag": "John Doe",
        "status": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "janedoe",
        "tag": "Jane Doe",
        "status": "0"
    }
]
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few options you have here but the simplest I suppose would be to change your `SQL` query like so:

```
SELECT 
  0 AS id, 
  user_login AS name, 
  display_name AS tag, 
  user_status AS status 
FROM wp_users;
```

You can see that now we have the needed order and when you will do the `$row['id'] = $i;` assignment we will use that position instead of creating a new `key => value`.

*Another solution making use of `MySQL` user variables:*

```
SELECT
  @idx := @idx + 1 AS id,
  user_login AS name, 
  display_name AS tag, 
  user_status AS status
FROM wp_users
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT @idx := 0) idx;
```

With the above solution you won't need to add the `PHP` increment mechanism, you will get the `id` column already formatted as you need.

Comment: Thanks @webtoure but sadly this won't work as the jQuery script requires all id's to be sequential. This will cause problems if a user deletes their account as the id values would jump. Say user 5 deleted their account, the id's would be "1,2,3,4,6,7 etc". That's why in this instance I'm not actually using the real user ID of the member.

Comment: Sorry @webtoure, just woke up after a late night and misread your solution. I thought you were grabbing the ID from the table which obviously, after a coffee, I can see that you're not. Your solution works perfectly. Thanks ;)